# Steam Web API Integration with ASP.NET site

Tags: asp.net, steam-web-api

I've been designing a website in ASP.NET, and I have been researching many ways to integrate the Steam Web API into my site. Whenever I try a method, it seems promising, but there is always a problem that I can't seem to overcome. Most of the methods online are using PHP, but I have not found a way to integrate this into my ASP.NET site either. I want users to be able to sign in through Steam, and to display inventories of certain users on the page. Any way of retrieving this data would be a huge step forward at this point.

The website is currently located at [Kritz.TF](http://kritz.tf). It's in a VERY early stage, I have been limited to what I can do before I do get this thing sorted out.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no problem explained here that anyone can help with. You need to post some code and the error message.

Comment: There is no error message, I am simply asking for any advice setting it up to begin with. There's 85 MB of code, I don't really know what to post?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845146/steam-login-authentication-c-sharp

Comment: Seems like something that would help, I'll give it a go, and see what happens :)

Comment: Works perfectly, thank for referring me Nick, if you want to leave an answer I'll accept it.